# RabbitMQ implementation of priority queues does not work as intended

Tags: python, rabbitmq, windows-10, pika

I am facing the following problem, which probably is due to my poor understanding of RabbitMQ. I am sorry if I don't use terminology for RabbitMQ experts.

In a few words, I want to publish to a queue a number of messages with different priorities, and I want a consumer to treat the higher priorities first.

I have declared my queue as:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters) 

channel = connection.channel() 

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)

channel.queue_declare(queue=JOBS_PENDING, durable=True, arguments={"x-max-priority": 1})
```

I use the following command to publish in that queue let's say 10 messages, the first 9 have priority 1 and the 10th has a higher priority let's say 2.

```
pika_props = pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2, priority=1 or 2)
channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key=JOBS_PENDING, body=message, properties=pika_props)
```

I have a separate service that consumes messages from the above queue.

```
channel.basic_consume(queue=JOBS_PENDING, on_message_callback=_encapsulate_callback(callback), arguments={"x-max-priority": 1})
```

To my understanding, doing this, the first message consumed should be the 10th because it has a priority higher than the maximum, which is 1.
Instead, what i see is that messages are consumed with the order of which they were published, i.e., the first 9 with priority 1 and the 10th last.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is when you declared the queue, you've defined that the message's max priority is 1.
In this case all of your messages will be treated the same, since your messages with priority two exceed the maximum value of priority, defined by you in the queue.

Set the maximum priority to any number larger than 1, for example 10. The messages with larger number will be prioritized first.

Check the [Documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html#resource-usage) for more details